# WPF TreeView - Confusing data binding and style for child nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I am confused of WPFs data binding and style declaration for TreeViews, especially for child nodes.

My ViewModel contains an object with the following hierarchy:

```
- Component1
  - SubcomponentA
  - SubcomponentB
- Component2
  - SubcomponentX
  - SubcomponentY
  - SubcomponentZ
```

I would like to modify the XAML file so I do not have to do anything within the .cs file.

This piece of code actually works:

```
<TreeView Name="tvComponent" ItemsSource="{Binding BpModule.BpComponentPrototypes.Elements}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding BpSubcomponents.Elements}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="cb_run"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
 </TreeView>
```

However, I would like to create different styles for root and child nodes.
I tried different approaches with almost completely different XAML code. But the major problem was to describe the dependency of the binding of child nodes to their parent and so they remained empty during runtime.

Can you help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, somehow I achieved to provide different designs for root and children nodes. Here is the XAML code:

```
<TreeView Name="tvSoftwareComponentPrototypes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BpModule.BpComponentPrototypes.Elements}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding BpSubcomponents.Elements}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Name="cb_run"></CheckBox>
                                <Image Source="/Resources/SubComponent.png" Margin="5,0,3,0" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Name="cb_swc" Checked="cb_swc_Checked" Unchecked="cb_swc_Unchecked"></CheckBox>
                            <Image Source="/Resources/Component.png" Margin="5,0,3,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

And the next problem is that I cannot access the Checkboxes at runtime.
WPF freaks me out :/

EDIT:

Hold on .. actually this is quite easy by changing the checkbox to the following XAML code:

```
 <CheckBox Name="cb_swc" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use the implicit `DataTemplate` mechanism (take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) to the DataType property). In this way you can define more `DataTemplates`, each one of them "linked" to a specific `Type`.

```
<TreeView Name="tvComponent" ItemsSource="{Binding BpModule.BpComponentPrototypes.Elements}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RootType}"ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
            ...
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ComponentType}" ItemsSource="{Binding BpSubcomponents.Elements}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="cb_run"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubcomponentType}">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Otherwise you can always use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) to create your own logic which chooses the right template for you.

Comment: This is one approaches I already tried out. 'Binding BpModule.BpComponentPrototypes.Elements' defines already my root Element. So what do I have to add to the ItemSource Binding within the RootType? 
Additionally, is the second "HierarchicalDataTemplate" implicitly bound to the root node?

Comment: Probably it would be better if you post the code of the objects (viewmodels) that your want to represent in your TreeView